# AQL traversal using path filtering

Tags: arangodb, aql

I am writing a graph traversal query in AQL (arangodb 3.1.22) where for some of the paths that are returned, I get a vertex within the path object that is not connected to any of the edges returned within the path object (i.e. the _from/_to property of the edges does not match the vertex _id).

I was working under the assumption that the path object only returned the vertices and edges on that path. Is this a wrong assumption?

Comment: Your assumption is correct, the path should only contain vertices and edges on the path. Can you post your query?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the starting point as string, no vertex has to exist at all for the traversal:

```
FOR v, e IN 1..10 OUTBOUND "nodes/non-existing-start" edges
    RETURN { vertex: v, _from: e._from, _to: e._to }
```

Data (vertices in collection `nodes` and edges in `edges`):

```
non-existing-start
      |
      v
non-existing-1
      |
      v
non-existing-2
      |
      v
non-existing-3
```

What it does is traverse along the edges (`_from` and `_to` properties), which do exist, using the edge index. The collection `nodes` has to exist, but it is not tested whether the vertices referenced in `_from` and `_to` actually exist in that collection. The query result is:

```
[
  {
    "vertex": null,
    "_from": "nodes/non-existing-start",
    "_to": "nodes/non-existing-1"
  },
  {
    "vertex": null,
    "_from": "nodes/non-existing-1",
    "_to": "nodes/non-existing-2"
  },
  {
    "vertex": null,
    "_from": "nodes/non-existing-2",
    "_to": "nodes/non-existing-3"
  }
]
```

As you can see, the vertices are `null`, so they don't exist.

You may use a managed graph and the [general-graph](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/Manual/Graphs/GeneralGraphs/) module to also [delete edges connected to a vertex](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/Manual/Graphs/GeneralGraphs/Management.html#remove-a-vertex) when deleting the vertex to ensure consistency.